# Showing $\int_a^b f \geq 0$ if $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$ and $f(x) \geq 0$ $\forall x \in [a, b]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, proof-writing

I am trying to show this is true, and what I have so far seems perhaps too simple. Nonetheless I will share what I have so far and see if there is room for improvement.

Suppose $P$ is a partition of $[a, b]$ in $n$ equal parts.
$$
P = \{ x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n \} \text{ where } x_i = a + \frac{i}{n} (b - a).
$$

Note that $U(f, P)$ and $L(f, P)$ denote the upper and lower sums of $f$ for $P$.

**The Proof (so far!)**

$$
\begin{align*}
f \text{ is integrable } \implies \int_a^b f &= \lim_{n\to \infty} U(f, P) = \lim_{n\to \infty} L(f, P) \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \frac{b-a}{n}\\
&= (b-a) \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)
\end{align*}
$$

It is clear that $b - a \geq 0$ and I want to say that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)} \geq 0$ because $f(x_i) \geq 0$. I just don't know how I can justify this.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Each lower sum $L(f,P)$ is bounded below by $0$, since $\inf_{x \in [a,b]} f(x) \geq 0$. Hence $0 \leq L(f,P) \leq \int_a^b f$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Ah yes, you're absolutely right. I must have been so stuck in my work I just needed to step back and remember the basics. Thanks!